# Why is that when adding 3+(x+9) i don't need to have the parenthesis surrounding it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Why is that when adding 3+(x+9) i don't need to have the parenthesis surrounding it?

I never understood this?

Comment: sorrounding what? you mean that you can remove the parenthesis?

Comment: You do have parenthesis. When computing, there is one addition that you do first. The thing is that $3+(x+9)=(3+x)+9$. That is why, when writing one can be sloppy and not write the parenthesis, because the result is going to be the same regardless of which addition is done first.

Comment: You seem to have asked this question before, and accepted a nice answer there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487751/when-do-you-get-rid-of-parenthesis-in-any-equation-when-do-i-know-when-parenthe

Answer (score 3):

They can be removed because addition is an associative operation. It makes no difference to the result if the parens are where you put them.

Compare this with an operation that isn’t associative, like $3-(x-9)$ and $(3-x)-9$

Answer (score 0):

Because addition is associative: that is, $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$, for all $a, b, c$.

So you might as well write $a+b+c$, since it doesn't matter where you put the parentheses.